# Excluding pages from the Composite.Navigation.DropDown function

Tags: xslt, c1-cms

The issue occurs when you create a page within the Content perspective that you do not want included in the navigation, when it gets generated:

---

[image]  [image]

---

When you use the Composite.Navigation.DropDown (XSLT) function to dynamically generate a navigation menu for a page, you specify a starting level, a subpage level, and whether or not to include a parent page.

[image: DropDown function parameters]

This DropDown XSLT function is inserted into a page template that is used across the site.

I have tried editing the XSLT Function to look for specific page types and/or page titles -- I did not have much luck there.

My current workaround is to add pages through the back-end (avoiding the Composite console). This is not such an elegant long-term solution.

Has anyone else ran into this and found a solution to get the DropDown function to exclude certain pages and/or page types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DropDown function should skip pages with empty "Menu title" property. Edit ypur page and make sure that Menu title is empty.
[image: Page Menu Title]

Comment: Thank you! There seems to still be an empty list item showing up when you hover over it, but this is most likely a CSS change on my end. I am accepting this as the answer.